# PHSchematron fails validating schematron file with `p` element inside `pattern` element

Tags: java, xml, validation, xslt, schematron

Currently I'm using PHSchematron library to validate schematron in Java. If I put `<sch:p>` tag as the child of `<sch:pattern>` then it throws NullPointerException, as SchematronOutputType is null.
I tried putting `<sch:p>` as child of `<sch:schema>` and `<sch:rule>` without any problems, though the XSD denotes that the `p` element could be child of `schema`, `phase`, `pattern`. 
I'm not sure whether the problem lies in the implementation of PHSchematron or not.
I'm supposed the xmlns:sch points to the 1.5 schematron XSD version.

schematron_1.5.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--  schemaVersion of 2001/02/15  -->
<xs:schema xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" xmlns="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" version="+//IDN sinica.edu.tw//SGML W3C XML Schema for Schematron 1.5//EN">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Get access to the xml: attribute groups for xml:lang
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:import>
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation source="http://www.ascc.net/xml/resource/schematron/schematron.html" xml:lang="en"/>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="active">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:dir"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:emph"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:span"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="pattern" type="xs:IDREF" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="assert">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:name"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:emph"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:dir"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:span"/>
                <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="test" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="role" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="diagnostics" type="xs:IDREFS"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute name="subject" type="xs:string" default="."/>
            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="diagnostic">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:value-of"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:emph"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:dir"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:span"/>
                <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="diagnostics">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="diagnostic" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="dir">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="value">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                                <xs:enumeration value="ltr"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="rtl"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:attribute>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="emph" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="extends">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="rule" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="key">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:NMTOKEN" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="name">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" default="."/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ns">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="uri" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="prefix" type="xs:NCName"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="p">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:dir"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:emph"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:span"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="class" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="pattern">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="p" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:rule" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="see" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="phase">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="sch:p" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:active" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="fpi" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="report">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:name"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:emph"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:dir"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:span"/>
                <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="test" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="role" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="diagnostics" type="xs:IDREFS"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute name="subject" type="xs:string" default="."/>
            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="rule">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:assert"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:report"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:key"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:extends"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="context" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="abstract" type="xs:boolean" default="false"/>
            <xs:attribute name="role" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="schema">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="sch:title" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:ns" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:p" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:phase" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:pattern" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:p" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:diagnostics" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
            <xs:attribute name="fpi" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="schemaVersion" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="defaultPhase" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute name="ns" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" default="1.5"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="assertId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:pattern/sch:rule/sch:assert"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:unique name="reportId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:pattern/sch:rule/sch:report"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:unique name="ruleId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:pattern/sch:rule"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:unique name="patternId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:pattern"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:unique name="pId">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//sch:p"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:key name="phaseId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:phase"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="activePattern" refer="patternId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:phase/sch:active"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@pattern"/>
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="extendsRule" refer="ruleId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:pattern/sch:rule/sch:extends"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@rule"/>
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="defaultPhase" refer="phaseId">
            <xs:selector xpath="."/>
            <xs:field xpath="@defaultPhase"/>
        </xs:keyref>
        <!--  Define the identity constraints  -->
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="span">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="class" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="title">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:dir"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="value-of">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="select" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

sample_schematron.sch

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema 
    xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
    queryBinding="xslt2"
    xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">   
   <sch:pattern id="sampleValidation">   
        <sch:title>PatternTitle</sch:title>
        <sch:p>A paragraph</sch:p>
        <sch:rule context="CCC">
            <assert test="normalize-space(.) and *">Source contains an empty element</assert>
        </sch:rule>  
   </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

SchematronUtil.java:

```
public class SchematronUtil {
    public static boolean validateXMLViaXSLTSchematron(@Nonnull final File aSchematronFile,
            @Nonnull final File aXMLFile) throws Exception {
        final ISchematronResource aResSCH = SchematronResourceSCH.fromFile(aSchematronFile);
        if (!aResSCH.isValidSchematron())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Schematron!");
        return aResSCH.getSchematronValidity(new StreamSource(aXMLFile)).isValid();
    }

    public static SchematronOutputType validateXMLViaXSLTSchematronFull(@Nonnull final File aSchematronFile,
            @Nonnull final File aXMLFile) throws Exception {
        final ISchematronResource aResSCH = SchematronResourceSCH.fromFile(aSchematronFile);
        if (!aResSCH.isValidSchematron())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Schematron!");
        return aResSCH.applySchematronValidationToSVRL(new StreamSource(aXMLFile));
    }

    public static boolean validateXMLViaPureSchematron(@Nonnull final File aSchematronFile,
            @Nonnull final File aXMLFile) throws Exception {
        final ISchematronResource aResPure = SchematronResourcePure.fromFile(aSchematronFile);
        if (!aResPure.isValidSchematron())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Schematron!");
        return aResPure.getSchematronValidity(new StreamSource(aXMLFile)).isValid();
    }

    public static boolean validateXMLViaPureSchematron2(@Nonnull final File aSchematronFile,
            @Nonnull final File aXMLFile) throws Exception {
        // Read the schematron from file
        final PSSchema aSchema = new PSReader(new FileSystemResource(aSchematronFile)).readSchema();
        if (!aSchema.isValid(new DoNothingPSErrorHandler()))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Schematron!");
        // Resolve the query binding to use
        final IPSQueryBinding aQueryBinding = PSQueryBindingRegistry
                .getQueryBindingOfNameOrThrow(aSchema.getQueryBinding());
        // Pre-process schema
        final PSPreprocessor aPreprocessor = new PSPreprocessor(aQueryBinding);
        aPreprocessor.setKeepTitles(true);
        final PSSchema aPreprocessedSchema = aPreprocessor.getAsPreprocessedSchema(aSchema);
        // Bind the pre-processed schema
        final IPSBoundSchema aBoundSchema = aQueryBinding.bind(aPreprocessedSchema, null, null, null, null);
        // Read the XML file
        final Document aXMLNode = DOMReader.readXMLDOM(aXMLFile);
        if (aXMLNode == null)
            return false;
        // Perform the validation
        return aBoundSchema.validatePartially(aXMLNode).isValid();
    }

    public static boolean readModifyAndWrite(@Nonnull final File aSchematronFile) throws Exception {
        final PSSchema aSchema = new PSReader(new FileSystemResource(aSchematronFile)).readSchema();
        final PSTitle aTitle = new PSTitle();
        aTitle.addText("Created by ph-schematron");
        aSchema.setTitle(aTitle);
        return MicroWriter.writeToFile(aSchema.getAsMicroElement(), aSchematronFile).isSuccess();
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
 SchematronOutputType outputType = SchematronUtil.validateXMLViaXSLTSchematronFull(schematronFile, xmlFile);

            if (outputType == null){
                throw new Exception("SchematronOutputType null");
            }

            List<SVRLSuccessfulReport> succeededList = SVRLHelper.getAllSuccessfulReports(outputType);
            for (SVRLSuccessfulReport succeededReport : succeededList){
                System.out.println(succeededReport.getTest());
            }

            int i = 1;
            List<SVRLFailedAssert> failedList = SVRLHelper.getAllFailedAssertions(outputType);
            for (SVRLFailedAssert failedAssert : failedList) {
                System.out.println(i++ + ". Location:" + failedAssert.getLocation());
                System.out.println("Test: " + failedAssert.getTest());
                System.out.println("Text: " + failedAssert.getText());

                List<DiagnosticReference> diagnisticReferences = failedAssert.getDiagnisticReferences();
                for (DiagnosticReference diagnisticRef : diagnisticReferences) {
                    System.out.println("Diag ref: " + diagnisticRef.getDiagnostic());
                    System.out.println("Diag text: " + diagnisticRef.getText());
                }
            }

            if (failedList.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("PASS");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            }
```

Comment: Why did you tag the question with `xslt`?

Comment: @MathiasMüller because I validate using XSLT2, PHSchematron supports XSLT and Pure Schematron validations

Answer (score 0):

Testing against the general ISO Schematron rules, your Schematron document is correct, except for the `targetNamespace` attribute. Having a default namespace in it `xmlns="..."` does not make much sense either, since all of the elements are prefixed.

**Schematron**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2">   
   <sch:pattern id="sampleValidation">   
        <sch:title>PatternTitle</sch:title>
        <sch:p>A paragraph</sch:p>
        <sch:rule context="CCC">
            <assert test="normalize-space(.) and *">Source contains an empty element</assert>
        </sch:rule>  
   </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

Then, the Schematron is fine, but there is a bunch of problems with the XML Schema. First of all, the namespaces in the XML Schema document are different. The Schematron file has `http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron`, while in the XSD it is `http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron`. This is most likely because you are using an age-old XML Schema for an older version of Schematron.

Having the correct namespaces should resolve the problem with `sch:p` not being allowed inside `sch:pattern`. After fixing the namespace issue in the XSD, the following problems remain:

```
Attribute 'queryBinding' is not allowed to appear in element 'sch:schema'.
Attribute 'name' must appear on element 'sch:pattern'.
Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron":title}'. One of '{"http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron":p, "http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron":rule}' is expected.
```

All of this can be fixed by modifying your XML Schema, the following is a version that works:

**XML Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--  schemaVersion of 2001/02/15  -->
<xs:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" version="+//IDN sinica.edu.tw//SGML W3C XML Schema for Schematron 1.5//EN">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Get access to the xml: attribute groups for xml:lang
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:import>
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation source="http://www.ascc.net/xml/resource/schematron/schematron.html" xml:lang="en"/>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="active">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:dir"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:emph"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:span"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="pattern" type="xs:IDREF" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="assert">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:name"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:emph"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:dir"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:span"/>
                <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="test" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="role" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="diagnostics" type="xs:IDREFS"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute name="subject" type="xs:string" default="."/>
            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="diagnostic">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:value-of"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:emph"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:dir"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:span"/>
                <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="diagnostics">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="diagnostic" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="dir">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="value">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                                <xs:enumeration value="ltr"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="rtl"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:attribute>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="emph" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="extends">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="rule" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="key">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:NMTOKEN" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="name">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" default="." />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ns">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="uri" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="prefix" type="xs:NCName"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="p">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:dir"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:emph"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:span"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="class" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="pattern">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="sch:title" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:p" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:rule" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute name="see" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="phase">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="sch:p" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:active" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="fpi" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="report">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:name"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:emph"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:dir"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:span"/>
                <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="test" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="role" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="diagnostics" type="xs:IDREFS"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute name="subject" type="xs:string" default="."/>
            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="rule">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:assert"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:report"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:key"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:extends"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="context" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="abstract" type="xs:boolean" default="false"/>
            <xs:attribute name="role" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="schema">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="sch:title" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:ns" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:p" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:phase" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:pattern" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:p" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="sch:diagnostics" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
            <xs:attribute name="fpi" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="schemaVersion" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="defaultPhase" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute name="ns" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" default="1.5"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
            <xs:attribute name="queryBinding" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="assertId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:pattern/sch:rule/sch:assert"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:unique name="reportId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:pattern/sch:rule/sch:report"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:unique name="ruleId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:pattern/sch:rule"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:unique name="patternId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:pattern"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:unique name="pId">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//sch:p"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:key name="phaseId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:phase"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="activePattern" refer="patternId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:phase/sch:active"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@pattern"/>
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="extendsRule" refer="ruleId">
            <xs:selector xpath="sch:pattern/sch:rule/sch:extends"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@rule"/>
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="defaultPhase" refer="phaseId">
            <xs:selector xpath="."/>
            <xs:field xpath="@defaultPhase"/>
        </xs:keyref>
        <!--  Define the identity constraints  -->
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="span">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="class" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="title">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="sch:dir"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="value-of">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="select" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But please keep in mind: this XSD document is outdated and does not reflect the latest changes to the Schematron specification. It is very likely that there will be other problems with it.

As an alternative, you could use recent [ISO Schematron and SQF schemas from Schematron Quickfix](https://github.com/schematron-quickfix/sqf/tree/master/schemas). Make sure you download all schema components and then validate against [iso-schematron.xsd](https://github.com/schematron-quickfix/sqf/blob/master/schemas/iso-schematron.xsd).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me the ISO Schematron XSD file. How do you test the validation of it, by Notepad++?

Comment: @Silentbang I have used Oxygen for testing, but I'm sure you can also do it with Notepad++ or a command line tool like xmllint. You need a tool that understands both XSD and Schematron, though.

Comment: @Silentbang So, did this solve your problem? Is anything missing from my answer? Please either accept this answer or let me know if there is something wrong with it.